# i got "Missing operand after 'Id' operator." error, what happen in my code friends?

Tags: c#

```
case 2:
    int intRemoveOption;
    Console.WriteLine("Select You Want to Delete Entire Column or Seperate:\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Select 11. for Remove Entire Column");
    Console.WriteLine("Select 12. For Remove Single Column\n");

    intRemoveOption = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (intRemoveOption ==11)
    {                         
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Id");                            
        objdatarowcollection = objDataTable.Select("student Id =");
        if (objdatarowcollection != null && objdatarowcollection.Length > 0)
            objdatarowcollection[0].Delete();
        Console.WriteLine("number of rows \n{0}", objDataTable.Rows.Count.ToString());                            
        Console.WriteLine("The Record is Deleted Now");
        datarow = objDataTable.Select();
    foreach (DataRow datarw in datarow)

        foreach (DataColumn datacl in datarw.Table.Columns)

            Console.WriteLine(" {0}", datarw[datacl]);
```

I tried lot but I can't, friends help this code, how to remove column?

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong

```
objdatarowcollection = objDataTable.Select("student Id =");
```

First, a field name with spaces requires square brackets around it.
Second, the Select method expects a syntax like you use in the sql WHERE statements. Thus, after the equals, you need a value to filter the row collection

```
 objdatarowcollection = objDataTable.Select("[student Id] =" + someValueToSearchFor);
```

Said that, your question is still unclear. What do you mean with "Remove Column"? You remove a column removing it from the DataTable in which it exists

For example:

```
  objDataTable.Columns.Remove("ColumnName");
```

Instead your code tries to delete the row at index 0 of the returned collection of row from the Select method, so if you want to remove a column:

```
objDataTable.Columns.Remove("C2");
+------+-----+------+                              +------+------+
|  c1  |  c2 |  c3  |                              |  c1  |  c3  |
+------+-----+------+                              +------+------+
|   A  |  D  |  G   |    Remove a column named c2  |   A  |  G   |
+------+-----+------+          result is           +------+------+ 
|   B  |  E  |  H   |                              |   B  |  H   |
+------+-----+------+                              +------+------+ 
|   C  |  F  |  I   |                              |   C  |  I   |
+------+-----+------+                              +------+------+
```

if you want to delete a row at index 0 of the returned collection 
(Notice that if the value to search for is a string you need quotes around the value)

```
objdatarowcollection = objDataTable.Select("C3 ='H'");
objdatarowcollection[0].Delete();
+------+-----+------+                              +------+-----+------+
|  c1  |  c2 |  c3  |                              |  c1  |  c2 |  c3  |
+------+-----+------+                              +------+-----+------+
|   A  |  D  |  G   |    Delete a ROW with value   |   A  |  D  |   G  |
+------+-----+------+  'H' in column c3 results in +------+-----+------+
|   B  |  E  |  H   |                              |   C  |  F  |   I  |
+------+-----+------+                              +------+-----+------+
|   C  |  F  |  I   |                              
+------+-----+------+
```

Keep in mind that here the words "remove/delete" are virtual.
The DataTable is an **in memory object**. Deleting elements from the in-memory row collection or removing from the column collection doesn't delete/remove anything in the database physical structure. For that you need real sql queries and the support of the ADO.NET provider of your database engine.

Comment: Then you need to know this "id" and add it at the end of the SELECT expression. Without it it is impossible to remove anything. By the way, remember that here the word "remove" is virtual. The DataTable is an in memory object. Removing elements from the in-memory row collection doesn't remove anything in the database physical structure.