# it shows ==>Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Id' operator

Tags: c#

```
namespace dt.cs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             DataTable objdatatable;
            DataRow objdatarow;
            DataRow[] objdatarowcollection;
            int intcount,intcount1;
            try
            {
                objdatatable = new DataTable("Student Details");
                objdatatable.Columns.Add("Student ID", typeof(string));
                objdatatable.Columns.Add("Student Name", typeof(string));
                objdatatable.Columns.Add("Phone No", typeof(string));



                for (intcount = 1; intcount <= 5; intcount++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("enter your choice:\n 1.Add Record \n 2.Delete Record \n 3.Update Record\n 4.table rename\n 5.View Record  \n 6.exit");

                    intcount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                    switch (intcount)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.WriteLine("\nHow Many Record You Want To Add:");
                            intcount1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                            for (intcount = 1; intcount <= intcount1; intcount++)
                            {
                                objdatarow = objdatatable.NewRow();
                                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Student Id:\n");
                                objdatarow["student Id"] = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Student Name:\n");
                                objdatarow["student Name"] = Console.ReadLine();
                                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter student Contact Number:\n");
                                objdatarow["phone no"] = Console.ReadLine();
                                objdatatable.Rows.Add(objdatarow);
                            }

                            break;

                        case 2:

                                 Console.WriteLine("Select Id for Delete Record");
                                 string stringname = Console.ReadLine();
                                 objdatarowcollection = objdatatable.Select("student Id ='" + stringname + "'");
                                 if(objdatarowcollection!=null && objdatarowcollection.Length > 0)
                                 objdatarowcollection[0].Delete();
                                 Console.WriteLine("The Number of Records \n{0}", objdatatable.Rows.Count.ToString());
                                 break;
```

This is my code, here i cant to delete particular record, what i was make mistake?

please find out my mistake friends
thanks in advance

Comment: i think this is my error line    objdatarowcollection = objdatatable.Select("student Id ='" + stringname + "'");

Comment: [You have asked the same question again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38801385/i-got-missing-operand-after-id-operator-error-what-happen-in-my-code-frien). What was not correct in the answer given there? By the way the answer accepted here cannot work because as it is now it is missing the quotes around the string value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decorate your column name with `[Table Name]` since it is composed of multiple words:

```
objdatarowcollection = objdatatable.Select("[student Id] ='" + stringname + "'");
```

**Side Note:** This is not a syntax error, but a run-time error caused by incorrect expression syntax.

Comment: _it's working_ ? very improbable without quotes around the string value

Comment: Until you input "ABC" in the stringname (the columns Student ID is defined as string)